# Pass a value from Controller to jQuery CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

This is Insert_model

```
class Insert_model extends CI_Model{
   public function idp(){
   $sql = sprintf("SELECT npd from `dosen`  ORDER BY npd DESC LIMIT 1");
   $query = $this->db->query($sql);
   foreach ($query->result_array() as $key ) {
       $npd1 = $key['npd'];
   }
   $kalimat1 = substr($npd1, 0,3);
   return $kalimat1;
}
```

This is a function from the Register Controller:

```
class Register extends CI_Controller{
  public $model;
  public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->helper(['url','html']);
      $this->load->database();
      $this->load->model('Insert_model');
      $this->model=$this->Insert_model;
  }
  public function index(){
      $nomor= array('npd' => $this->model->idp());
      echo json_encode($nomor);
  }
}
```

This is how I access the $nomor value via Ajax:

```
$("#status").on("change", function(){
var x = $("#status option:selected").attr("value");
if(x=='mahasiswa'){
    $.ajax({
        url:'<?php echo base_url();?>register/index',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(nomor){
            $('#nomor').attr('placeholder',nomor.npd);
        },
    });
});
```

I want to be able to pass `$nomor` from the Register Controller to use it on my jQuery file. I tried to use `json_encode()`  on the Controller and actually it didn't work.

Comment: You are not *POSTING* any data, so try to change `type: 'POST',` to `type: 'GET',`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and I tried using type: 'GET' not working

Comment: Is `$nomor` variable has values before it sends to your script? Please double check.. Also, while manipulating JS scripts, always clear your cache to refresh the browsers memory and read the updated JS file again.

Comment: Is there an error message? Can you access the url in the ajax directly in the browser? assuming it's a 'GET' action.

Comment: if you're using "npd " inside an array,your output must be like this [ npd = [11,22,33]] ,so in your jquery,you must loop the npd first

Comment: Show your model code

Answer (score 0):

Try with controller:
Ref : https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html

```
$this->load->model('model_name');
$data['npd'] = $this->model_name->method();
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: '$this->model->idp()' this indicate directly calling method without loading model..I did not found model loading statement.

Comment: Your answer and question have no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
public function index(){
      $nomor= array('npd' => $this->model->idp());
      echo json_encode($nomor);
      exit();
  }
```

i hope this will help you